# Finding $H'(1)$

Tags: calculus

Given $H(x)=F(x)G(x)$ Find $H'(1)$

Suppose:

$F(1)=2$

$F'(1)=3$

$G(1)=5$

$G'(1)=-2$

Then using the product rule I assumed $H(1)=11$ because:

$H(1)=((2)(-2))+((3)(5))=11$ using the product rule. However I am unsure as to how to derrive $H'(1)$ from $H(1)$ Would anyone mind giving me some insight on this?

Comment: You have $H'(1) = (2)(-2) + (3)(5)$, not $H(1)$.

Comment: How is it?  I must be missing something. do you mind explaining that real quick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$H'(x)=F(x)G'(x)+G(x)F'(x),$$ and so 
$$H'(1)=F(1)G'(1)+G(1)F'(1)=2 \cdot (-2)+5 \cdot 3=11.$$
There is not much else to say here.

Comment: Ah I was thinking it was H(x)=F(x)G'(x)+G(x)F'(x) for some reason and now that I think about that it makes no sense why I thought that. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. It sounds like you get it. :))

Answer (score 1):

If H(x) = F(x)G(x) then H'(x) = F'(x)G(x) + F(x)G'(x) by the product rule. Then simply substitute the given values.

H(1) = F(1)G(1) = 2 * 5 = 10

H'(1) = F'(1)G(1) + F(1)G'(1) = (3 * 5) + (2 * (-2)) = 15 - 4 = 11

I think what you did wrong is that you thought that H(x) = F'(x)G(x) + F(x)G'(x), but no, it was already given that H(x) = F(x)G(x). I hope that helped you to understand.